# Redirect URL with query to new URL with same query

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am looking to create a redirection flow-through on a website that can take a URL such as:

```
https://example.com/go/asset?tag=1234567
```

And can redirect it to:

```
https://newexample.com?asset=1234567
```

I think I might be close, but can't seem to get it working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /go/asset$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag=\d{7}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newexample.com?asset=%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I saw a few similar examples that have informed my attempt, but nothing specific to my use case. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out with some additional testing, here's the working redirect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\basset\b=(\d{7}))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newexample.com?asset=%2 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

This testing tool was particularly helpful:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/